# Why am I getting the same column twice in my PHP | PostgreSQL query?

Tags: php, postgresql

I have a Postgres database from which I retrieve data with a PHP script. Inside this script I connect through PDO:

```
$connection = new PDO('pgsql:host=' . $host . ';dbname=' . $database, $username, $password);
```

Then, I have a query which should just list the `id` of each instance:

```
$query = 'SELECT id FROM my_table WHERE "myCondition" = TRUE';
```

Then I am getting the result of my query:

```
$result = $connection->prepare($query) or die($connection->error);
$result-> execute();
```

And finally, I print my results:

```
foreach($result AS $row) {
    echo var_dump($row);
};
```

---

Now my problem is that I get an array of two values in my browser for each `$row`, even though I am only asking to return `id`:

> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(3) "GNQ" [0]=> string(3) "GNQ" }

So somehow I am getting a second value, again with the `id` but with a different key identifier (in that case the index). What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns the same value twice because of PDO fetch type. Default is `PDO::FETCH_BOTH` which means "return columns as indexed from 0 and with names". If you want to return only named indexes just add fourth param to PDO constructor with array of options (https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php).

```php
$connection = new PDO(
    'pgsql:host=' . $host . ';dbname=' . $database, 
    $username, 
    $password, 
    [\PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => \PDO::FETCH_OBJ]
);
```